# Android Google Drive API v2, retrieve files from certain account

Tags: android, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-client, google-drive-android-api

I'm developing an android application, on Certain action I want to retrieve some files from specific GDrive account (say: abc@gmail.com). which stores application related files.

Is that possible? if yes ca anyone provide examples or point me to tutorial?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: will you be using the REST API or the Android API?

Comment: Android API prefered

Answer (score 1):

I the files are created outside of your Android app, they will be visible only under DRIVE_FILE scope, limiting you to use of the [REST](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/about-sdk) API.

If the objects are created by the Android app itself, you have a choice to use REST or [GDAA](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/intro) API since both of them support the FILE scope (i.e. seeing files/folders created by that Android App only).

There are 2 official demos on GitHub, both GDAA flavor. The [QuickStart](https://github.com/googledrive/android-quickstart) and the [AndroidDemos](https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos), afaik, both of the GDAA flavor.

I've also published a rudimentary CRUD wrappers of both the [REST](https://github.com/seanpjanson/RESTDemo) and the [GDAA](https://github.com/seanpjanson/GDAADemo) APIs (they also deal with the account selection process in the MainActivity).

**UPDATE:**
To be more specific, the retrieval of files is accomplished [here](https://github.com/seanpjanson/RESTDemo/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/andyscan/gdrtdemo/REST.java#L123), (for the REST but you'll find an equivalent *search* method in the GDAA implementation). Notice that there are many ways you can modify the query. The best place to test it interactively is [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list) (bottom of the page).

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the file picker available in the GDAA. It allows you to browse files available to the authenticated user, including files "shared with" the user so if files belonging to abc@gmail.com are shared with the authenticated user your app can interact with them.

Usage of file picker is demonstrated here:
https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos/blob/master/src/com/google/android/gms/drive/sample/demo/PickFileWithOpenerActivity.java